# Retrieving the List of data from SOAP response under specific tag using C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, soap

I am trying to load the SOAP response data into c# model object as a list to save that in the data base. Below is the code that I tried but not good to access the data

```
using (WebResponse Serviceres = Request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                //reading stream  
                var ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                var doc = XDocument.Parse(ServiceResult);
                
                //My though is to load the data in c# model object
                //Tried doc.Elements("Records") etc
```

Below is the response that I am getting from the SOAP request

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
<QueryResult xmlns='http://www.niku.com/xog/Query' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <Code>cpcf_Project_Code</Code>
  <Records>
    <Record>
      <Id>5029026</Id>
      <Name>Admin</Name>
      <Code>1006</Code>
      <Status>Approved</Status>
      <IsActive>1</IsActive>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Id>50236</Id>
      <Name>USA</Name>
      <Code>10426</Code>
      <Status>Approved</Status>
      <IsActive>1</IsActive>
    </Record>
  </Records>
  <Slice>
    <Number>0</Number>
    <Size>7268</Size>
    <Total>7268</Total>
  </Slice>
</QueryResult>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to get help from you guys with the best approach to retrieve the data and save it in DB. Your comments are most valuable at this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by this way :

1 - Class

```
public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

2 - code :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace xn = "http://www.niku.com/xog/Query";

List<Record> records = doc.Descendants(xn + "Record")
    .Select(x => new Record
    {
        Id = int.Parse(x.Element(xn + "Id").Value),
        Name = x.Element(xn + "Name").Value,
        Code = int.Parse(x.Element(xn + "Code").Value),
        Status = x.Element(xn + "Status").Value,
        IsActive = x.Element(xn + "IsActive").Value == "1",
    }).ToList();
```

Note that, I considered that the values ​​of `IsActive` take `1` or `0`.

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you Sajid, I tried using it but is still having null values in doc.Descendants("Record"). 

 var ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
 var doc = XDocument.Parse(ServiceResult ); would there be another way to get the data

Comment: Thank you Sajid, It worked just as good that I expected .